# Can't center SpanLabel with BorderLayout

Tags: codenameone

If I do that :

```
Label lbl = new Label("My Label");
Form f = new Form("Test");
BorderLayout bl = new BorderLayout();
f.setLayout(bl);
f.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, lbl);
f.show();
```

`Label` `lbl` is well centered in my form (horizontally and vertically).
If you replace `lbl` instance with `SpanLabel`, it's not centered at all.
Is it normal ? If so, how to centered it ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Multiline text needs to behave differently from single line text as it's non-deterministic. It calculates its size based on columns and not the real content.

I wrote about the challenges of this a while back here: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/the-challenge-of-multiline-strings.html